# cakephp 3 SMTP on DigitalOcean

Tags: cakephp, smtp, gmail, digital-ocean, cakephp-3.x

I can´t send email on digitalOcean droplet with ubuntu, php7 and cakephp3

In my localhost it works but in production I get timeout error.

I've done everything and many ways and no works.

see my app.config

```
'EmailTransport' => [
 'default' => [
    'className' => 'Smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' =>'MYuser',
    'password' => 'MYpwd',
    'client' => null,
    'tls' => true,
    'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),

],
```

],

Can someone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

DigitalOcean blocks for 60 days new Droplets to send email for "security reasons".

If you need a server for host a site whos send email, don't choice DigitalOcean.

Comment: If you resolved it thanks to my answer, it's considered polite to accept my answer instead of posting your own copy.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, I founded answer before you post.
but, ok!

Comment: @GregSchmidt, I can't vote because i don't have reputation.
For year I have same number of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Digital Ocean blocks outgoing SMTP ports by default. You'll have to ask them to unblock them, and they may wait a while before doing so.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/not-able-to-connect-to-gmail-smtp

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have to enable port `25`. According to their support, they mentioned like this;

```
sudo ufw allow 25
sudo ufw reload
```

Or you may not have enough money for support SLA.

Comment: I do this. Thanks